# which angular2 js file should be added in on the client side?

Tags: npm, angular

I am a semi noob in web development.

I just started playing around with angular2 today. And i ran into a problem..

If I were to install angular2 with npm to my local computer, which file is the js file that should be linked to the html page that show up on the client?

In their guide, i see a file called /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.sfx.dev.js. But i don't even see this file at all.

Is there some script that i should run to build that file? Or is the file renamed? I am really confused.

I tried some file /angular2/bundles/angular2.js, but it doesn't even export ng variable to window!

I see that in https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.44/angular2.sfx.dev.js, eventually ng gets exported. But what changed in alpha 53? (the version i get for doing npm install angular2)

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md, sorry I don't have time now to investigate further.

Comment: To be honest that just confused me even further. I tried to read it, didn't understand any thing haha. Like i said im semi noob.

Comment: The SFX bundle was replaced by the UMD bundle (this bundle is for people who wants to write in plain ES5 without using TS nor SystemJS, etc). If you are planning to use TS you should use `angular.js. This [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3458) may be helpful, and you should track this other [one](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5777).

Comment: @EricMartinez I tested out the UMD bundle, but the global ng object does not seems to be the same object in their Angular2 start guide instructions. For starter, it doesn't have ng.Component (Component is nested under ng.core)

Comment: You're right, that was a breaking change, check the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: to get the same version in the tutorial do `npm install angular2@2.0.0-alpha.44`, your question is confusing, please specify your problem?

Comment: @MurhafSousli I'm trying to use the latest version (53), i guess i shouldn't be following the documentations too closely for a library in alpha... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In my projects, I a using

"node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"

You might additionally need to install/add systemjs, just in case you are using the systemjs library.